# multiple image upload and write data as json array into json file

Tags: json

Am completely new to JSON. I need to upload multiple images and write data(image path with name) into json file in the form of json array. Have googled but did not get relevant information. Can anyone help to how to commence?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is typically not used for binary data like images so that's why you don't see people explaining how to do that.

Comment: I just want to store image names with path which are being selected into json file as an array